# In Python combine two iterator based on time

Tags: python, iterator, timestamp

I'd like to combine two iterators and yield the value(s) of the iterator that has the highest timestamp.

Minimal example and expectations:

```py
# Outputs of these generators are "timestamps"
def gen_even():
    for x in range(0, 11, 2):
        yield x
        
def gen_odd():
    for x in sorted(list(range(1, 15, 2)) + [6]):
        yield x
```

Combining these two should result in in the following sequence
`[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, (6, 6), 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 13]`

I tried the following which runs into `StopIteration` after gen1 has been consumed.

```py
gen1 = gen_even()
gen2 = gen_odd()

def gen_both(gen1, gen2):
    first = next(gen1)
    second = next(gen2)
    
    while True:   
        if first < second:
            yield first
            first = next(gen1)
        elif first == second:  
            yield first, second
            first = next(gen1)
            second = next(gen2)            
        else:
            yield second
            second = next(gen2)


gen = gen_both(gen1, gen2)

for i in gen:
    print(i)
```

Output:

```py
0
1
2
3
4
5
(6, 6)
7
8
9
10
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
StopIteration                             Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[8], line 11, in gen_both(gen1, gen2)
     10     yield first
---> 11     first = next(gen1)
     12 elif first == second:  

StopIteration: 

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[8], line 21
     18             second = next(gen2)
     20 gen = gen_both(gen1, gen2)
---> 21 for i in gen:
     22     print(i)

RuntimeError: generator raised StopIteration
```

How can I do this in Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could avoid the stop iterator by handling it as follows:

```
def gen_both(gen1, gen2):
    first = next(gen1, None)
    second = next(gen2, None)
    
    while True:
        if first is None and second is None:
            break
        elif first is None:
            yield second
            second = next(gen2, None)
        elif second is None:
            yield first
            first = next(gen1, None)
        else:
            if first < second:
                yield first
                first = next(gen1, None)
            elif first == second:  
                yield first, second
                first = next(gen1, None)
                second = next(gen2, None)            
            else:
                yield second
                second = next(gen2, None)
```

Comment: true. this works as you know, that None would never be part of the payload.
SO None is fine and no sentinel value is needed.

Comment: If you ever needed a solution to go through two iterators, where None might be a valid value you could use a sentinel value.
ITER_EXPIRED = object()

and then you use
next(gen1, ITER_EXPIRED)

Comment: @gelonida this is a good suggestion

Comment: well for this particular question not needed and perhaps overkill. but perhaps useful for similar scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

One not very elegant but working approach would be following:

Marco F.s approach is defintiely nicer.

below approach uses one sub function, that is being used to yield results until one of the two generators is exhausted
and yields then the result of the remaining data of the other generator.

My solution is clumsy but has a very small advantage if one of the two generatos is way larger than the other.
In that case it might be a little more performant, but I doubt the difference would be of any importance

```
def gen_both_part1(gen1, gen2):
    first = next(gen1)
    second = next(gen2)

    while True:
        if first < second:
            yield first
            try:
                first = next(gen1)
            except StopIteration:
                return
        elif first == second:
            yield first, second
            try:
                first = next(gen1)
            except StopIteration:
                return
            try:
                second = next(gen2)
            except StopIteration:
                yield first
                return
        else:
            yield second
            try:
                second = next(gen2)
            except StopIteration:
                return

def gen_both(gen1, gen2):
    for val in gen_both_part1(gen1, gen2):
        yield val
    for val in gen1:
        yield val
    for val in gen2:
        yield val
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
def gen_even():
    for x in range(0, 11, 2):
        yield x


def gen_odd():
    for x in sorted(list(range(1, 15, 2)) + [6]):
        yield x


def gen_both(even, odd):

    x = next(even, None)
    y = next(odd, None)

    while x is not None and y is not None:
        if x < y:
            yield x
            x = next(even, None)
        elif x == y:
            yield x, y
            x = next(even, None)
            y = next(odd, None)
        else:
            yield y
            y = next(odd, None)

    gen = even

    if x is not None:
        yield x
    else:
        gen = odd

    for i in gen:
        yield i


for x in gen_both(gen_even(), gen_odd()):
    print(x)
```

Comment: I'm not sure this would be working as this code always gets one next value from gen1 and one fron gen2
but if gen1 one yield something like 1,2, 3, 4
and gen2 would yield 10, 11

then you would yield
1, 10, 2, 11, 3, 4

Comment: Good point, I'll fix it

Comment: OK, that should work :)